# attaching more than two virtual disks to a virtual machine in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, virtual-disk

I'm installing OSISoft on a single windows 2008 VM in Azure and part of the instructions recommends having 4 drives for each application.  However Azure will only allow 2 disks be attached to a VM.  What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use data disks and choose the different VM size - the VM size determines the amount of data disks that can be connected. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/

Tutorial:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-attach-disk/

Comment: VM size was the problem.

Comment: This answer has some inaccuracies. First: "At least standard A2" is not really accurate - it's based on cores: You can attach 2 x cores. So, basic tier works fine as well. Second: Not true that data is wiped out after reboots. Data *may* be lost at any time due to the in-chassis disks being non-durable. But they normally survive reboots (you'll likely lose data on those disks during VM resize though). Some databases are designed to replicate across machines, and work fine with non-durable storage.

Comment: I think the first paragraph would have been sufficient for an answer the problem was not virtual disk storage and config.. a D2_V2 Standard is what I opted for..Either way it pointed me in the right direction, I overlooked the disk restrictions when orginally setting up the VM